# AC Origins - Isfet fight without heavy attack

Tags: assassins-creed-origins

Every guide for the Isfet-fight in Origins says "use heavy attack". Well, I got no skill points left and didn't skill this one yet. Any ideas how I could win this fight otherwise? Or am I doomed to start the game over?

Comment: Heavy attack doesn't require skill points; _charged_ heavy attack does. You can beat Isfet with just regular heavy attack. I did it by doing alternating heavy attack and dodge until the adrenaline gauge was full, and then finishing him off with overpower. I'm well past that particular fight and still don't have charged heavy attack skill, so I know I'm not misremembering. :)

Comment: Thanks for the input. Though I did start over, I still haven't done the fight again, so I'll ty tonight, I think.